# Same session on multiple tabs

Tags: java, session

I have some problem here if an user open multiple tabs on a browser with same session.

1. User open tab 1, navigate to trade 1001 details
2. Right click and open another tab on same browser, navigate to trade 1002 details
3. Go back to tab 1, and amend the trade 1001 details. Instead, trade 1001 details is overwritten with trade 1002 details.

I am using WebSphere 8.0. The page is request-scoped.

Any advise on what would be a good and easy to maintain solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

you are saving transactional detail in session/cookies which is a bad idea, the ids etc. should be passed as hidden fields in the form.

Comment: I concur, you should use ID (primary key) to determine the object that should be updated, when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Ankit Gupta How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you using any framework, jsf etc? If you are manually creating a form you can add a input field of type hidden and pass the id as value.

Comment: @Ankit Gupta Yes. I am using JSF 2.0, xhtml

Answer (score 0):

A vote-up for Ankit, when you're opening a new tab, make sure that you have a tab-specific id as a hidden input field e.g. a product id.

From this point on, you can take two path, the stateless approach, not using sessions at all, loading back everything from the DB, updating, saving. Stateless is a bliss, if you can support it perfect. 
The second approach assumes that you're using the tab-specific id to retrieve the right date from your session, so in another words, your tab-specific id would be a part of the session key.

The later approach means that you've enabled a conversation scope, and since you mentioned you're using JSF, there's a support for conversations, check out the docs for  [@ConversationScoped](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html). The key line is

```
Any JSF request has exactly one associated conversation.
```

Concrete examples depend on the implementation you use, should find plenty of examples online, my idea was just to let you know its supported